# 'Statement' Attribute in SQl Server Auditing Log File

Tags: sql-server, auditing

Can anyone plz tell me how can i read the value of parameteres in the sql server audit log file's statement attribute.
for example : i fired a query 
select name from some_table where id='someID'

In log file i get the entry in the statement attribute as
Select from [some_table] where [id]=@1

So can someone help me to get the value of this @1???

Answer (score 0):

You can record the queries as they are executed by using trace (with SQL Server profiler for example) and logging the [RPC:Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175543.aspx) event.